# React vite is giving me error while setup of react-snap

Tags: reactjs, seo, vite, react-snap

getting error in setup of react-snap in React vite
I tried this + "source": "/dist" it creates 200.html how do i solve this problem

```
  pageerror at /: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

    "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "postbuild": "react-snap"
  },
  "reactSnap": {
    "source": "dist"
  },


 "reactSnap": {
    "source": "dist"
  },
```